# In bash, how to pass an optional argument with the current dir as default?

Tags: bash

I am trying to define my customized cp function, which is something like

```
mycp() {
cp -r "$1" "${2:$PWD}"
}
```

where the second argument is optional and should be the current path by default. However, when I run that it always returns an error of `"No such file or directory: ''"` when there is no 2nd argument, and `bash: 2: <mypath> : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<mypath>")` argument when I passed `.` as 2nd argument.
What did I miss here?

Answer (score 2):

**You can do the following (the main thing missing was the `-` in `:-` from `"${2:-$PWD}"`:**

```
mycp() {
cp -r "$1" "${2:-$PWD}"
}
```

Comment: This is documented in the manual: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)